# Take minimum of 2 nullable datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, compare, nullable

I have 2 Nullable Datetime field's in a method. How to select minimum of 2.

I tried below:

```
    static void GetMinimunDate(DateTime? startDate,DateTime? copDateTime)
    {
         DateTime? retDate = DateTime.MinValue;

        if (startDate == null && copDateTime == null)
        {

        }
        else if(startDate.HasValue && copDateTime.HasValue)
        {
            retDate = startDate < copDateTime ? startDate : copDateTime;
        }
        else if (startDate == null)
        {
            retDate = copDateTime;
        }
        else
        {
            retDate = startDate;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just compare their `Value` properties and see which one is smaller.

Comment: So where's the problem

Comment: Want to check if there is a better way. If one is null i want other value

Comment: You can write a generic method to calculate Min or Max for any type like below:

    `public static T Max<T>(T FirstArgument, T SecondArgument) {
        if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(FirstArgument, SecondArgument) > 0)
            return FirstArgument;
        return SecondArgument;
    }`

Then use like below:

`var result = new[]{datetime1, datetime2, datetime3}.Max();`

Comment: public static DateTime? Min(DateTime? firstArgument, DateTime? secondArgument)
  {
   if (Nullable.Compare(firstArgument, secondArgument) > 0) 
    return firstArgument; 
   return secondArgument;
  }